# Ubuntu 18.04: Unable to create files using an executable which is made to run via a script

Tags: php, shell, ubuntu, permissions

Using PHP's system/exec commands to run a script that in-turn makes an executable run, that executable when run directly via terminal generates 2 text files successfully but fails to do so when it is made to run using command in php, which is:

```
system("bash run.sh");
```

this run.sh contains command which executes an executable. contents of run.sh are:

```
#!/bin/bash
./op 2
```

where `op` is an executable file, which successfully creates two text files only when run using a terminal.

Comment: You forgot to specify in your post in which way it fails. Also, did you verify that $PWD is the same in both cases?

Comment: There are lot of things to check viz. the directory where the php script runs and the actual executable runs. File, folder permissions to create a file. If you are calling PHP script via browser then if the webserver user has proper permission or not.

Comment: it fails as in it doesnt run.. i mean when i type ./op 2 in terminal, it executes fine and generates standard output .. but when i type something like this $output = exec('./op 2') it doesnt work. i have another a.out file in this folder also which executes fine, its kind of a weird problem.

Comment: Now after appending 2>&1 to the command i am getting this error..../op: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by ./op) ./op: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./op) ... 
Whereas standalone when i run the shell file directly , it works fine , no dependency issues..